# Django-REST framework restore_object attrs parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Finding the Django-REST framework documentation to be, despite how lengthy it is, still too light on background for me.

What does the restore_object method's attrs function do?

```
instance.title = attrs.get('title', instance.title)
```

What does the second argument stand for, and how would I go about looking for what this would mean in the future in the docs?

Also not sure what the double asterisks in `return Snippet(**attrs)` means.  This is different from **keywArgs ?  What arguments are being passed back to the deserialized Snippet object?

In another section of the docs, I see in restore_object() `instance.title = attrs['title']` which I hope one might be able to see my confusion.

thank you

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pk = serializers.Field()  # Note: `Field` is an untyped read-only field.
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False,
                                  max_length=100)
    code = serializers.CharField(widget=widgets.Textarea,
                                 max_length=100000)
    linenos = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    language = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES,
                                       default='python')
    style = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES,
                                    default='friendly')

    def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
        """
        Create or update a new snippet instance.
        """
        if instance:
            # Update existing instance
            instance.title = attrs.get('title', instance.title)
            instance.code = attrs.get('code', instance.code)
            instance.linenos = attrs.get('linenos', instance.linenos)
            instance.language = attrs.get('language', instance.language)
            instance.style = attrs.get('style', instance.style)
            return instance

        # Create new instance
        return Snippet(**attrs)
```

Comment: I was wondering the exact same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've updated the documentation slightly in an aim to make that more clear...

http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization.html#creating-a-serializer-class

The method now reads...

```
def restore_object(self, attrs, instance=None):
    """
    Create or update a new snippet instance, given a dictionary
    of deserialized field values.

    Note that if we don't define this method, then deserializing
    data will simply return a dictionary of items.
    """
    if instance:
        # Update existing instance
        instance.title = attrs.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.code = attrs.get('code', instance.code)
        instance.linenos = attrs.get('linenos', instance.linenos)
        instance.language = attrs.get('language', instance.language)
        instance.style = attrs.get('style', instance.style)
        return instance

    # Create new instance
    return Snippet(**attrs)
```

The `**attrs` style is using Python's standard keyword expansion.
See [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/#calling-a-function) for a good explanation.

It'll end up as the equivalent of `Snippet(title=attrs['title'], code=attrs['code'], ...)`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Tom, great framework.  You look so young, but I guess that's who all the ninjas are these days.  In retrospect, the **attrs is very obvious, I just did not know about this in my adventures in Python.  It's all very clearly documented, it was a bit hard to search for this in Google.  I know that documentation doesn't need to teach people Python and Django, that's out of scope.  But making the added comments does help people like me I'm sure.

Comment: Hi Tom, How do you use attrs.get() for nested serializers?

Comment: Hi Tom, it is unclear to me as when instance will be equal to None, as well Its unclear to as what instance is can you elaborate ?

Comment: `instance` will be `None`, unless the serializer was instantiated with an existing model instance to be updated, using the `instance=...` argument.

Comment: @Tom Christie I understand how instance can be set to None or not in the django code itself.  By when I'm posting to the url of the element, how do I indicate I'm trying to update an existing instance?  When I enter a PK that already exists, since it's an autofield it just creates a new instance.

Answer (score 4):

In DRF 3.0+ the restore_object method was removed. Now you can use two separate methods: .create and .update

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data): 
    instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title) 
    instance.code = validated_data.get('code', instance.code) 
    instance.linenos = validated_data.get('linenos', instance.linenos)
    instance.language = validated_data.get('language', instance.language)         
    instance.style = validated_data.get('style', instance.style)  
    instance.save() 
    return instance 

def create(self, validated_data): 
    return Snippet.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Release notes: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/